# Updating OpenGL ES 2.0 Textures on Preference Change

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm making an android live wallpaper using OpenGL ES, and I've based the code off of the tutorial from 
http://www.learnopengles.com/how-to-use-opengl-es-2-in-an-android-live-wallpaper/

I am currently trying to make it so that switching the preferences will swap out the textures for different ones. I wanted to make it so that all of the textures would be loaded at the beginning, but there are a lot of textures, and that would take too long (I can't have a loading screen like a game, so the wallpaper has to load in under a second which means < 3.0 mb of textures). I've decided that it would probably be best to switch textures by using the texSubImage2D method and the good news is that I've implemented this like so in the renderer class:

```
String imageID = preferences.getString("texture_model", "1");
    Log.d("texture change", "changeTexture called with imageID: " + preferences.getString("texture_model", "1"));
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.girl2crop);
    switch(imageID)
    {
        case "1":
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.girl2crop);
            Log.d("texture change", "texture 1 called");
            break;
        case "2":
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.girlstudentcrop);
            Log.d("texture change", "texture 2 called");
            break;
        case "3":
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.girlbluecrop);
            Log.d("texture change", "texture 3 called");
            break;
    }

    // Bind texture to texturename
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturenames[1]);
    GLUtils.texSubImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0,0, bmp);

    bmp.recycle();
```

Because this can only be called from the GL main thread, I've used this bit of code in the WallpaperService class to call that method in the render class:

```
@Override
  public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible)
  {
      super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);
          if (visible)
          {
              glSurfaceView.onResume();
              sensorManager.registerListener(this,accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
              Log.d("onResume", "was called on " + glSurfaceView.toString());
          } else
          {
              if(rendererHasBeenSet)
              {
                  glSurfaceView.queueEvent(new Runnable()
                  {
                      // This method will be called on the rendering
                      // thread:
                      public void run()
                      {
                          renderer.refresh();
                      }
                  });

              glSurfaceView.onPause();
              sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
              Log.d("onPause", "was called on " + glSurfaceView.toString());
          }
      }
  }
```

The problem that I'm running into is that every time I switch the preferences, the wallpaper does change, but only after the wallpaper is "refreshed" (resumed, paused and resumed again via opening another app, or rotating the home screen). The changes aren't happening immediately, and I need them to. Does anyone know how to fix this, or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the only way this works immediately is to place the queueEvent method right after the onresume method. Thinking about this, I guess it makes sense.

```
  @Override
  public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible)
  {
      super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);
          if (visible)
          {
              glSurfaceView.onResume();
              glSurfaceView.queueEvent(new Runnable()
              {
                  // This method will be called on the rendering
                  // thread:
                  public void run()
                  {
                      renderer.refresh();
                  }
              });
              sensorManager.registerListener(this,accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
              Log.d("onResume", "was called on " + glSurfaceView.toString());
          } else
          {
              if(rendererHasBeenSet)
              {
              glSurfaceView.onPause();
              sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
              Log.d("onPause", "was called on " + glSurfaceView.toString());
          }
      }
  }
```